# Top Level Where Used (Combined Cells)

Tags: excel, vba

I have top level where used report. I am having difficulty to consolidate the child part used in which Model and Product.

How do I combine the text in multiple columns if there is value in the cell?

Data screenshot
[image: Data screenshot]

Comment: Sorry, but could you please explain what are you trying to achieve? Also, you tagged the question with VBA so please, post the code you've tried, where are you stuck and what errors are you getting.

Comment: Probably you can do it with formulas, could you add the expected result and share what you have already done. thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Filter()` function to create array of products or models, the use `Concat()` to combine them. If you need a delimiter, it should be included before the `Concat()` function with an ampersand. if required, use a `Left()` function to remove last delimiter.
Example:

> =LEFT(CONCAT(FILTER($C$2:$F$2,$C5:$F5=1)&";"),LEN(CONCAT(FILTER($C$2:$F$2,$C5:$F5=1)&";"))-1)

[image: Finished sheet]

Comment: you really help me on this!